# I don't know how to approach a limit problem.

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I need to find the limit of
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big(\frac{1+n^2+n^3+...+n^{10}}{2+n^2+n^3+...+n^{10}}\Big)^\sqrt[n]{4}. 
$$ First of all I found the limit of $\sqrt[n]{4}$ is $1$. Now I don't know how to do the limit inside the round brackets.

Comment: Did you mean $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Inside the bracket tends to 1.... Just the numerator and denominator by $n^{10}$

Comment: What happens if you factor out the fastest term in the numerator and the denominator and cancel it.

Comment: @A.gamma exactly

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thank you!